# How to import xml package to databricks

Tags: xml, python-import, databricks

Any one follow the following links before about xml 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

I just keep having problem on importing import com.databricks.spark.xml._

Error

[image]

My databricks version

[image]

Actually I also want to know how to install the package

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.12:0.5.0
```

Comment: Please post that code and error message as text.

Answer (score 1):

You can install package/library by using import library option available in databricks homepage.

[image: databricks-homepage]

Here choose maven option and give maven coordinates or you have the privilege to search package as well

[image: maven]

[image]

After this you need to attach the library to your cluster by navigating Clusters>Libraries.
Now you can directly use this library as below without importing it.

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').options(rowTag='book').load(' /FileStore/tables/sample.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency in Android Studio:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml
compile group: 'com.databricks', name: 'spark-xml_2.12', version: '0.5.0'
```

For further assistance, follow this link:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks

Comment: Can we do on Azure portal databricks??

Comment: @MichaelChau, Seriously I don't have an idea, but mostly checked Maven Repository if I didn't find the required dependencies. I don't have an idea about the Azure portal. But did the dependency worked for you?